# How to query the pushes for a device?

Tags: pushbullet

I want to use [`Pushbullet`](https://www.pushbullet.com/) to send pushes from my phone to an application (which will then display it). This application is a service written in Python.

The basic reception of the realtime stream works:

```
import websocket

ws = websocket.create_connection("wss://stream.pushbullet.com/websocket/MYKEY")
while True:
    result = ws.recv()
    print"Received '%s'" % result
```

When pushing something to "All Devices", I get the expected output:

```
Received '{"type": "nop"}'
Received '{"type": "nop"}'
Received '{"type": "tickle", "subtype": "push"}'
Received '{"type": "nop"}'
Received '{"type": "tickle", "subtype": "push"}'
```

What I receive does not contain any data, the type is '`tickle`', and [the documentation says](https://docs.pushbullet.com/#http) that

> When you receive a tickle message, it means that a resource of the
>   type subtype has changed.

and to query the details on the server. The call which is mentioned there (`GET https://api.pushbullet.com/v2/pushes?modified_after=1399008037.849`) is not authenticated, so how to actually make the call?

**Alternatively**, I wanted to create a "device" for my application and send the pushes to it directly. But I cannot find any place in the docs where the process of impersonating a device would be described?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I gave a try to a `GET` with the `Authorization` header and it worked:

```
# ts is the timestamp one wants to check from on
ts = 0
headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer MYKEY'}
    r = requests.get(
        'https://api.pushbullet.com/v2/pushes?modified_after={ts}'.format(ts=ts),
        headers=headers
    )
```

Since `target_device_iden` is sent with the push details when the push is directed to a specific device, my guess is that there is no "impersonation" (per the second part of my question): every device gets the whole feed and selects the events which were specifically directed to it (or mirrored ones)

Comment: You are correct, there is only a single stream per user.  Devices decide themselves if they want to display a notification.  You can create devices though, that is documented at https://docs.pushbullet.com/